# redux-thunk delete action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual tengo que utilizar *redux-thunk* alguien podría darme  un buen pantallazo de manera lógica por que en este código se le pasa al *action creator* el parámetro de esta forma:

```
const _removeBook = ({ id } = {}) => ({
    type: 'REMOVE_BOOK',
    id
});
 
export const removeBook = ({ id } = {}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.delete(`books/${id}`).then(() => {
            dispatch(_removeBook({ id }));
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mejor simplificar los parámetros. En ves de poner como parámetros `{ id }`, puedes simplemente poner `id`.

A veces, algunos devs hacen desestructuración en Redux pero no es necesario. Sólo necesitas desestructurar/hacer desestructuración (*destructuring* en inglés) en los componentes React con los props. Puedes cambiar el código a esto:

```
const removeBookSuccess = (id) => ({
  type: 'REMOVE_BOOK_SUCCESS',
  id
})

export const removeBook = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_BOOK', id })

  axios
    .delete(`books/${id}`)
    .then(() => {
      // Si llegas aquí, debes ver en Redux Dev Tools:
      //    REMOVE_BOOK
      //    REMOVE_BOOK_SUCCESS
      dispatch(removeBookSuccess(id))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Si ves eso, tienes un error del API
      dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_BOOK_ERROR' })
      console.error('>> ERROR', error)
    })
}
```

Los *action creators* en Redux Thunk tienen que devolver una función que tiene el `dispatch` en los argumentos. También hay `getState`:

```
const removeBook = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => { }
```

Si necesitas accesar el state de Redux, puedes hacerlo aquí. También si necesitas buscar informaciones de un API, puedes hacer una operación asincrónica y reaccionar al éxito o al fracaso.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo decía la respuesta anterior es mejor colocar `id` solamente e igualmente una buena manera y la mejor de ejecutar una action de Redux es hacer lo siguiente:

```
const _removeBook = ( id ) => ({
type: types.removeBook,
payload: id
})
```

Donde types es un objeto que tiene `removeBook: "REMOVE_BOOK"`y todas las que necesites.
y el payload donde va toda la información (si has usado el useReducer lo sabrás) así que en el reducer en vez de tomar la data sola la tomas como `action.payload`

La operación asíncrona puede ser usando un `async await` Es decir: `return async (Dispatch) => { }` la respuesta la tomas como: `const resp = axios.delete('url')`
Y después de esa línea verificas que tenga un status 200 o una respuesta `OK` dentro de la respuesta y con un simple `if( estado === 200 || resp.ok === true)` decides si ejecutar el `dispatch` o no